# Specific Network Informations

Tags: android, network-programming

I'm doing a school project where I need to retrieve all the Access Point I can find near me.
When I get the List mScanResultList I can access to the fields I need.
The code I'm testing is:

```
for(ScanResult r : mResultList) {
                    Log.i(TEST, "BSSID: " + r.BSSID);
                    Log.i(TEST, "SSID: " + r.SSID);
                    Log.i(TEST, "Frequency: " + r.frequency);
                    Log.i(TEST, "Level: " + r.level);
                    Log.i(TEST, "Capabilities: " + r.capabilities);
                }
```

My question is:
r.level is a negative value. I need that decibel strength to convert it into approximate distance. Should I just do -(r.level)?

In addition I need to know the "Security Type: WEP, WPA, Open ..." (citing the project assignment). Where do I get those info from? I can't understand what r.capabilities means.

the Capabilities field of a network I find reads:

```
Capabilities: [WPA-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPA2-PSK-CCMP+TKIP][WPS][ESS]
```

Comment: Does the school project really want distance or just best candidate?

Answer (score 0):

The Capabilities field tells you the capabilities of the Access-Point (including encryption).

I don't know what API you used to get r.level but it might be negative or positive depending on the wireless driver that is being used. It normally is just what the chip equates the RSSI to (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_signal_strength_indication). You would probably do well to just take the absolute value of r.level. Also keep in mind that the closer r.level is to zero (no matter negative or positive) the stronger the received signal..if that makes sense. As for equating r.level to distance, you will have to make some assumptions and it will never be exact.